# replacing lists with empty lists in a table

Tags: kdb

A user was asking how to create a select statement that replaces long lists with empty long lists in a table column for certain rows (given by a where constraint).

sample table

```
t: ([] myCol: 3 cut til 10)
```

He was complaining that this returns a `length` error:

```
update myCol: `long$() from t where i in 0 2
'length
  [0]  update myCol: `long$() from t where i in 0 2
                                                ^
```

which is expected because the list assignment requires both lists to have the same length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach is `count[i]#enlist`

```
update myCol:count[i]#enlist`long$() from t where i in 0 2
```

Comment: This also looks good. The reason I would choose the sublist-based solution is to avoid hardcoding the type, and to avoid typing the punctuations ;)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the function `sublist` with `each`

```
update 0 sublist' myCol from t where i in 0 2
```

Is there any other solution that is worth consideration?

Comment: You can drop the `sublist` and go straight to the take operator in this case

Comment: I prefer `sublist` because qbies can understand it. The take operator is overloaded and causes frustration for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Terry's answer is the most idiomatic method, but it's worth noting that you can also use the [take](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/take/) operator to create empty lists.

```
q)0#til 5
`long$()
q)update 0#'myCol from t where i in 0 2
myCol
--------
`long$()
3 4 5
`long$()
,9
```